# Error loading Microsoft Speech SDK v11

Tags: c#, microsoft-speech-api

I have installed the x86 SDK and added the Microsoft.Speech.dll to my project. The project is set to x86.

When trying to create a instance of `SpeechSynthesizer` I get

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {D941651C-44E6-4C17-BADF-C36826FC3424} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

What more can cause those then wrong target platform?

Comment: Shot from the hip: Do you use .NET Client profile as your target framework? Although I would not suppose this to be the issue, considering the error message...

Comment: No its 4.5 thats target framework

Comment: Used System.Speech instead

Comment: @Anders, Have you solved the problem? I have the similar issue. Can you share your solution?

Comment: I'm using the Managed code wrapper found in System.Speech instead, my source code can be found here https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core.Plugins/SpeechPlugin.cs

Answer (score 4):

I resolved these issues a few minutes ago:

-Download and using Microsoft Speech SDK 32 bit (By this way you can use in both platforms)

And the most important is to install these files :

-In Microsoft Speech SDK:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\v11.0\Redist\SpeechPlatformRuntime.msi
```

-In Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime Languages:

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224

MSSpeech_SR_en-US_TELE.msi (using for Speech To Text)
MSSpeech_TTS_en-US_ZiraPro.msi (using for Text To Speech)
```

That done.

Comment: Any advantgges over the managed code discussed above? https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.Core.Plugins/SpeechPlugin.cs